# SSRS Conditional Exprssn

Tags: reporting-services

Please help me to solve this issue.
I am new to SSRS.

I am trying to sum up the `Amount (w/o Tax)` based on different product categories like `AEC,MCL,MFG` & so on..
I used IIF & Sum Conditions but it throws an error.

Here I have pasted the conditional expression plz go through it.

```
=IIf(((Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="AEC",sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value)),IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="ASB",sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="MCL",sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="ME",sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="MFG",sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="TRG",sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="SUB",sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),0))
```

Comment: And what is the error? If you've using visual studio it should give some explanation in the warnings panel

Comment: =sum(IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="AEC",sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="ASB",sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="MCL",sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="ME",sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="MFG",sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="TRG",sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="SUB"),sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),0))

Comment: hello JonnusSyntax error in value expression..

Comment: ,Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to be doing it using a nested if statement, and not formatting it correctly.

If you insert line breaks and indentation into your calculation you can easily see where it's going wrong

```
=IIf(
        (
            (Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="AEC",
                sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value)
            ),
            IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="ASB",
                sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),
                IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="MCL",
                    sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),
                    IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="ME",
                        sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),
                        IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="MFG",
                            sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),
                            IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="TRG",
                                sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),
                                IIf(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="SUB",
                                    sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value)
                                    ,0)
                                )
```

Those opening braces `(` don't belong, your first `IIF` is doesn't have enough conditions, and there aren't nearly enough close braces  `)` to finish the expression off.

I'm not sure a nested if is the right function to be using here - a [SWITCH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx) would make much more sense, i.e.

```
=SWITCH(Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="AEC", sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),
    Fields!Prod_Horz_Category.Value="ASB", sum(Fields!Amt_w_o_Tax.Value),
    ...
)
```

Comment: Let us know how you get on and if you need further assistance